# Xml Serialization - Don't include element when no data present

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am currently using the XmlSerializer class to write out certain data to an XML document, however when a particular field contains no data it is currently writing it out like the following:

```
<ElementA />
```

Is it possible to have the element not written out at all if no data exists for that field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ShouldSerilize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/53b8022e(v=vs.71)) method.
In your class you just need to implement `bool ShouldSerilizeElementA()` method, e.g.:

```
 public bool ShouldSerilizeElementA() => ElementA != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate [How do I tell xmlwriter to ignore empty nodes in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926582/how-do-i-tell-xmlwriter-to-ignore-empty-nodes-in-c):

Detailed description on this approach is [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/StrippingOutEmptyXmlElementsInAPerformantWayAndTheBusFactor.aspx).

Short: Use a Regex to kill empty elements out of the resulting string.

```
static Regex regex = new Regex(@"\<[\w-_.: ]*\>\<\!\[CDATA\[\]\]\>\</[\w-_.: ]*\>|\<[\w-_.: ]*\>\</[\w-_.: ]*\>|<[\w-_.: ]*/\>|\<[\w-_.: ]*[/]+\>|\<[\w-_.: ]*[\s]xmlns[:\w]*=""[\w-/_.: ]*""\>\</[\w-_.: ]*\>|<[\w-_.: ]*[\s]xmlns[:\w]*=""[\w-/_.: ]*""[\s]*/\>|\<[\w-_.: ]*[\s]xmlns[:\w]*=""[\w-/_.: ]*""\>\<\!\[CDATA\[\]\]\>\</[\w-_.: ]*\>",RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Here, this way is used to write a custom XMLWriter / XMLReader class, which does not omit the empty elements.